# Setting up WSL1 and WSL2 side-by-side

Tags: windows, wsl2

I've succeeded in installing WSL2 on top of WSL1 that I already had installed following the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065419/how-to-run-multiple-wsl2-instances-on-windows/66067679#66067679

Since I want to have both distributions running side-by-side, I didn't reset the old image to a clean state as it was suggested in that answer.

Currently, I am running the new distribution from powershell by typing:
`wsl ~ -d Ubuntu18.04_clone` What do I need to do in order to allow running it in the same way I run the old one, that is through the start menu by typing "Ubuntu" (ideally, I would name it something like 'Ubuntu-18.04_WSL2') whilst also keeping the old distribution runnable from the start menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing *"Ubuntu"* in the Start Menu is what's called an "Application Execution Alias".  That's a "fake `.exe`" that runs an application installed from the Microsoft Store (a.k.a. "Modern", "Metro", "Universal", "Windows" app, or "UWP" -- They've been [renamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps) more times than Prince).

But it would be overkill to create your own Store application and execution alias.  What you want can be accomplished with a simple Shortcut in the Start Menu.

However, before I get into how to do that, let me recommend a few alternatives:

- Windows Terminal is the modern Microsoft replacement for the legacy Windows Console.  It will automatically detect all of your WSL distributions and install them as Profiles.  If you are running Windows 11, you can even set it as the default Terminal so that the shortcut we create below will launch your new Ubuntu distribution in it.
- Alternatively, the *"Power Run"* app from [Microsoft Power Toys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) can detect and run Windows Profiles along with any other type of application (and many other search results) with an approach similar to the macOS Spotlight search.  The hotkey for activating it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

  *Edit/Update*: This method has become my preferred method for several reasons:

  - It returns results *fast* - Faster than the Windows 11 Start menu at least.
  - It can be set to return Windows Terminal profiles at the top of the search results, so typing "Ub" will show all my Ubuntu profiles first.
  - It's a fuzzy search, so typing "ub 2" would pull up your `Ubuntu-18.04_WSL2` profile.
  - You can even use a prefix <kbd>_</kbd> (or define your own) to *only* return Terminal profiles.
  - Side note: You'll probably want to enable the *"Open Profiles in New Tab"* option in the Power Run settings for Terminal.  This will keep it from creating new windows for each invocation.
- *Previous preferred method*: It's also possible to launch Terminal Profiles fairly quickly from the keyboard inside Terminal with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, followed by <kbd>.</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch the "New Tab ..." Menu, then typing the name of any Windows Terminal profile.  It sounds like a complicated keychord, but I've gotten quite used to it.  That said, the Power Run method has replaced this for me.
- But yes, it's hard to break the <kbd>Win</kbd>, so setting up a Start menu shortcut can be a good option, too.  To do so:

  1. Open *File Explorer*
  2. Navigate to
     `C:\Users\dcrozier\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
  3. Right-click in an empty area and Choose *"New Shortcut"*
  4. Set the *"Location"* to `wsl ~ -d Ubuntu18.04_clone` as you've
     specified above
  5. Set the name to whatever you want to call it, such as `Ubuntu-18.04_WSL2`

  That's it - After a few seconds to index it, the Start menu should show your new distribution/instance and allow you to launch it directly.